# GoogleMLKit/TextRecognition examples

Tags: google-mlkit

I have been using Firebase/MLVision, Firebase/MLVisionTextModel for ios but due to recent migration, I need to upgrade my application. Do we have some links on the forum for reference?
I am using the below method to recognize the text currently - nsFirebase.mlkit.textrecognition.recognizeTextOnDevice so I think that with the upgrade, I will need to change method call too? If yes, where can I find some documentation.
Please advice.
Thanks
Jyoti

Answer (score 1):

The migration guide for moving your app from Firebase ML to the new standalone ML Kit SDK can be found here: [Overview](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/migration), [Android-specific instructions](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/migration/android), [iOS-specific instructions](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/migration/ios).